# Unable to connect debugger to Jelly Bean Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, debugging, android-4.2-jelly-bean

We have a Jelly Bean Galaxy Nexus from Google IO, and have all the latest updates to the Android SDK installed - but we are unable to use USB Debugging on the device from Intellij IDEA.

We set our project to compile using the 4.1 SDK, etc.. no luck. Does anyone know how to get USB debugging working on the new Jelly Bean Galaxy Nexus?

(edit)
This is being tried from a Mac running OS X 10.7.4 - so in theory drivers should not be an issue?

Comment: After you enabled USB Debugging from the device, did the drivers get installed when you plugged it in?

Comment: Jelly Bean drivers differ from the ICS drivers unfortunately. You'll have to find the appropriate drivers before debugging

Comment: I'll edit to point out that I'm on a mac, and so drivers shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: Does adb devices at the command line show anything? Can you run whatever the osx version of lsusb is, with and without it connected, to find its vid?

Comment: Can you use adb to find the device?

Comment: It does display I am adb that it's connected, and I can install apps and run logcat... But the debugger will not connect.

Comment: Okay, that's different than the problem most of us thought you had.  Make sure the apk is built as debuggable, and perhaps as an experiment try running the eclipse java debugger (instead) using the newest tools and sdk?  If you run DDMS, do you get detailed information within debuggable apk's, or just an overview?

Comment: The APK is marked as debuggable, but in DDMS all we see (besides logs) is the device, no process information

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  When trying to launch an app with multiple potential devices, the Android Device Chooser dialog pops up asking which device to run the app on.  I see the phone, with the correct target (4.1) and state (Online), but the Debug field does not say "Yes" like the other devices.

Comment: That sounds like the exact issue I have, JT703

Comment: @Matthew I find it hard to believe that no has done any USB dubbing on Jelly Bean.  I feel like we're just missing something.  I have a weird feeling it's something in the developer options screen on the phone.

Comment: @JT703 FYI, the Debug field of the Device Chooser doesn't have to say "Yes" to be able to debug. I believe that field just indicates whether your firmware is signed with test keys. Most production devices won't say "Yes" in that field.

Comment: Oddly enough, things work just fine with our Jelly Bean Nexus 7...

Comment: I've encounter the problem too. All Mac, Linux adb devices, lsusb and the notification bar says no debug on a GN with JB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, opening the Android SDK manager and making sure everything is up to date (it was), and then restarting IDEA fixed this. I can now connect to the Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 19):

Latest android seems to hide the developer menu in settings, here's the game you have to play to get it back:

> 1. Settings->About phone
> 2. scroll down to the bottom until you see Build number
> 3. click on Build number 7 times

You are now a developer.
Go back to the main settings menu and you'll have the developer menu again

Comment: Thanks, no way I could have figured this out. Wish I could +50 for this.

Comment: I have Android 4.1.2 on an Alcatel onetouch and there appears to be a different (newer?) way to activate USB debugging. When you go to Settings->About phone, instead of tapping 7 times on the build number, use the "Advanced settings" choice at the top of the list. This has a setting for turning on USB debugging.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this kind of problem on my Nexus 7 (no problem with my Galaxy Nexus) by changing the usb connection from MTP to PTP.

Go to settings > Storage > corner menu > USB computer connection > select "PTP".

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Mac OS 10.8 and managed to have ADB and the debugger working with the Nexus 7 after installing Google's Filetransfer application:

http://www.android.com/filetransfer/

Answer (score 0):

I have been having issues trying to get IntelliJ to recognize my nexus 7 ever since I installed it. I was about to go back to windows 7 until I found @eyal-lezmy suggestion. Tried it and everything works great. Mind you I tried getting latest drivers for the laptop and from the Android SDK nothing would work till I changed the connection type from mtp to ptp. Also windows detected the device just that IntteliJ would not.